# Accessing Google Spreadsheet feed during downtime

Tags: google-docs, google-docs-api, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am wondering if there is any information on how the published feed of a spreadsheet may be affected by a temporary period of downtime to the Google Docs Spreadsheets service.

Would the feeds still be available during this period or downtime? 
Are there any circumstances in which a feed may not be available?

I would assume that feeds are cached.

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous circumstances here that make this a difficult question to answer, primarily because portions of Google Spreadsheets could be "down", even though the system is still usable.

For the most part, though:  If Google Spreadsheets were *completely* down, then yes, the Google Spreadsheets API would also be down.  The feeds are not cached.

Applications using the Google Spreadsheets API should implement local caching as a best practice.